# Optimizing pandas operation for column intersection

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 2 columns (event and events) . Event column contains a particular eventid and events column contain list of event Ids.

Example :-

```
df 
event   events
'a'       ['x','y','abc','a']
'b'      ['x','y','c','a'] 
'c'       ['a','c']
'd'        ['b']
```

I want to create another column(eventoccured) indicating whether event isin events.

```
eventoccured 
1
0
1
0
```

I am currently using

```
df['eventoccured']= df.apply(lambda x: x['event'] in x['events'], axis=1)
```

which gives the desired result but is slow, I want a faster solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is use list comprehension:

```
#40k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [217]: %timeit df['eventoccured']= df.apply(lambda x: x['event'] in x['events'], axis=1)
1.15 s ± 36.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [218]: %timeit df['eventoccured1'] = [x in y for x, y in zip(df['event'], df['events'])]
15.2 ms ± 135 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be even slower than `apply`?

Comment: @DeepSpace - Tested and it is faster.

Comment: The solution has cut down the execution time by half. I was wondering how come the difference time in @jazrael experiment was tremendous (100 times) but I only gained by 50%. Is it because of some internal caching mechanism of pandas, as in the experiment dataframe had repeated values ?

Comment: @KaranGautam - I think it depends of number of rows, number of values in each list, so in real data should be different performance. Not sure if python optimalize same values, I guess not (but maybe I am wrong)